# Problem with beep sound in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the below code in my app to make a beep sound. Its working in my system iPad simulator (both 4.2 and 4.3). But it not making a beep sound in my iPad iOs 4.2.

my code is:

```
NSURL *tapSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BEEPJAZZ" withExtension: @"WAV"];   
self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];    
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (soundFileObject);
```

Comment: Note that file names in device are case sensitive.

Comment: ok..i used audioplayer with same url.it working fine in my ipad.but i dont know why this not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code. Still try to use following code. From one of my working project.

```
NSString *tapSoundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BEEPJAZZ" ofType:@"WAV"];
self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tapSoundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(knifeSoundUrl, &soundFileObject);  
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (soundFileObject);
```

Hope it works.